# Vlookup in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

Good day.

Is it possible to change a cell when it is found using Vlookup?

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(y, worksheet.range, 2, False)
```

returns a value for x, based on what was found using Vlookup.  But, can you change that cell to another value, such as

```
 Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Y, worksheet.range, 2, False) = z
```

Comment: Hi, is the value of x already known? we can replace the values using excel formulas. But I am not sure if I understand the requirement. Do u want to change the value of the cell if vlookup retrieves some value? if you could provide with the example it will be better.

Comment: In the future, you may want to look at the MATCH function. It is like half of VLOOKUP - you give it a row or column, and it looks for a search term and tells you how many cells in it went to find it.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon  Thanks, but not exactly what I was looking for.  I wanted to change a value in a column.  I needed to find the row first.  Using find and a range.address I was able to find the row.  From there I used offset to get to the column.

Comment: @KSK I needed to find the row for a certain value so I could offset from there to a column and change the value in that cell(Rrow,Coffset).  Find worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, vlookup gives you the value in the cell it finds, not a reference to the value property of the cell.  You will need to use the find method to find the relevant cell in the range of matching values, then use offset to move over to the column that contains the value you want to change.

I am no excel vba person, but i think something like this should work...

```
worksheet.range.Find(Y, lookin:=xlValues).Offset(0,2).Value = z
```

I am assuming that "worksheet.range" holds a valid range of cells.  Also, if you expect more than one match, you might need to loop through the results of the Find.  I forget if Offset just grabs the first cell in the range and then offsets from that.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to find.  I used the following code and was able to identify the cell I needed to change.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using the find function borrowed from http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm. 'Dim Rng As Range
   With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")   Set Rng = .Find(What:=X, _ After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count),  LookIn:=xlFormulas,  LookAt:=xlWhole, _ SearchOrder:=xlByRows,  SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) If Not Rng Is Nothing Then  msgbox rng.address Else  msgBox "Nothing found" End If  End With' I wanted to find in column "A" a match for a variable (which is known).  Once the row is found, using the rng.address I was able to use offset to change a value in a col.